# How to Create JSON from Multiple Attachment

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a form where user can add one or more attachment using this code

```
<div id="attachments">
</div>
<a href="#" id="addAttachment">Add attachment</a>

<script>
$("#addAttachment").click(function () {
    var strChooseFile = "<table><tr><td><input type='file' name='PostedFiles' size='30' title='Choose file ...'></td>";
    strChooseFile += "<td><input type='text' name='FileDescriptions' size='50' title='File descriptions ...'></td>";
    strChooseFile += "<td><input type='button' name='btnAttachmentRemove' id='btnRemoveAttachment' value='Remove' ></td></tr></table>";

    inputFile = $(strChooseFile);
    inputFile.clone(true).appendTo("#attachments");
});
</script>
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.sanwebe.com/2014/04/ajax-contact-form-attachment-jquery-php) to prepare the data before being sent to the server. Below the code how I prepared the data:

```
$("#btnAddInvoice").click(function (e) {
    if ($("#frmInvoice").validate().form()) {
        var m_data = new FormData();
        m_data.append("SubsidiaryClientID", $("#SubsidiaryClientID").val());
        m_data.append("SubsidiaryClientNo", $("#SubsidiaryClientNo").val());
        m_data.append("SubsidiaryClientName", $("#SubsidiaryClientName").val());
        m_data.append("PostedFiles", $("input[name=PostedFiles]").val()); // how to parse this to json?
        m_data.append("FileDescriptions", $("input[name=FileDescriptions]").val()); // how to parse this to json?

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Content("~/Invoice/AddInvoice")",
            data: m_data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
            if (!data.message) {
                $("#invoiceList").html(data);
                $("#addInvoiceModal").modal("hide");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see in the code above, I've a problem when prepared `PostedFiles` and `FileDescriptions`. After being sent to the controller, the values is null.

How to prepared `PostedFiles` from array of `$("input[name=PostedFiles]")` and also `FileDescriptions`?

Comment: Can you give us an example value of your inputs please? Along with how you'd like them to be 'parsed' for submission to the server. As an aside, that markup in javascript makes my head hurt. Might be worth throwing all of this in a jsfiddle so we can help you restructure it.

Comment: is the input[name=PostedFiles] an input file? and the input[name=FileDescriptions] input?

Comment: Firstly `m_data.append("PostedFiles", $("input[name=PostedFiles]").val());` (and the following line) wont work. It would be easiest to just serialize your form (including the files) - [refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)

Comment: @Infer-On Yes, PostedFiles is an `<input type="file" />` and FileDescriptions is `<input type="text" />` as you can see in the script. It's dynamic and can be more than 1

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke, it works, how smart you are :) could you add it as an answer. Btw, I have serialized the form using `$("#frmInvoice").serialize(),` but it doens't work. Could you explain it in the your answer?

Comment: Actually I have marked it as a duplicate :)